# REGEXP Query not working properly with variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have issue to apply a Codeigniter Query from a code inserted with jquery into a database, i just only need the alphanumeric characters.

i been using REGEXP to clean up the characters that i don't want, the query works if i type the characters directly in the query but it doesn't if i use a variable from another query.

```
<?php    
    $this->db->select('niv');
    $this->db->from('tbl_notes');
    $this->db->where('notes_id', $notes_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()){
        $niv = $query->result();
    }
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_flotilla_history');
    $this->db->where('notes REGEXP ', "'.*;s:[0-9]+:\"$niv\".*'", false); 
    $this->db->limit(10);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()){
        $history = $query->result();
    }
?>
```

The result of the query is empty when i put $niv variable in the other query

How i can solve this?

Regards

Comment: try `$this->db->where('notes REGEXP ', "'.*;s:[0-9]+:\"".$niv."\".*'", false); `

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<?php
    $history = NULL;
    $this->db->select('niv');
    $this->db->from('tbl_notes');
    $this->db->where('notes_id', $notes_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()) $niv = $query->result();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_flotilla_history');
    $this->db->where('notes REGEXP ', '".*;s:[0-9]+:\"'.$niv.'\".*"', false);
    $this->db->limit(10);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()) $history = $query->result();
```